# how to password protect a single page (that's not apart of an authentication system)?

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor, password-protection

I'm building a Meteor app for contracts. A signed in user can create a contract. But I'd like for them to be able to send a contract to another party, who can view the contract without signing up or creating an account. The problem is that, even if the URL is long and random, www.example.com/docs/bM7GjrRq1wABYdxws3 -- I'm not sure it is private enough -- because maybe all these contracts could be easily crawled or end up in search [like this](https://grahamcluley.com/2014/05/dropbox-box-leak/).

I'd like the creator of the contract to set a password that can be emailed to the other party along with the link to the contract. Before the party can view the contract, they need to enter the password.

My solution is to allow a user to password protect the page (but without a username/email). But I'm not sure how to do it. How can I password protect a page with a password set by a user?

Answer (score 0):

You could save password within the page object on mongodb.
Then when he creates or edit the page, he might choose to share publicly or with password.

The publish method could look somewhat like this.

```
Meteor.publish("page", function (){
    if (!this.userId) {
        return Pages.find({
            _id: Session.get("pageId"),
            private: true,
            password: Session.get("pagePassword")
        });
    } else {
        // code for logged in users
    }
});
```

Of course it's a good idea to store a hash for the password and compare to the hash the user entered, instead of storing the raw password.